# Exists a Spark Dataframes Write Option possible Values list?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I´m a beginner in Spark and i´m trying to find a list with the possible key/values for ".option" when i´m using "Dataframe.write".

So i need a list with the possible key/values that i can use in ".option"
Now i know i can use "maxRecorsPerFile",100 but i´m sure exitst other key/values that i can use with .option.

I´m looking in the doc but i can´t find anything....

Thanks so much!

```
df.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile",100).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("Description").format("csv").save("c:\\csv\\dfcanceladoParticionadoPorColumnaMaximoFilasFichero")
```

Comment: your question is bit unclear, what are you looking for ?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I want to know which keys or Keys/values exists in Spark what i can use inside .option() because i have found ("maxRecorsPerFile",100) but i want to know which other "things" exists for .option

Comment: here you go. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?

Comment: For example maybe exists .option("maxSizePerFile","1g") ...

Comment: The documentaion doesn´t show the options...

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter